SQL Server "echo" while running long script
Is it possible to somehow "echo" messages in SQL scripts in SQL Server, so they can get recorded in the execution log?
Due to strong security policies the developers can only run database scripts in the dev environment, and they can see the result of them right away.
However, to perform changes in the test, staging, or prod databases they need to submit SQL scripts, get them reviewed, approved, and finally run. Once they are run the DBA sends an execution log that looks like:
(12 rows affected)
(1 row affected)
(141 rows affected)
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 21
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.
(5 row affected)
(1 row affected)

In the example above 6 queries were executed and it's simple enough to get that the fourth one had issues. In this small set it's easy to find the bad query in the original script.
It's not easy anymore, when there are 250 queries run on a script. Is there any way to include messages such as "Step #1 complete" in the log, as in:
(12 rows affected)
(1 row affected)
-- Step #1 complete
(141 rows affected)
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 21
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.
(5 row affected)
-- Step #2 complete
(1 row affected)


You mean PRINT?

@ThomA Never even occurred to me. Should it take this form? fiddle. If that looks good, please add an answer so I can accept it.

Just need to adjust my search criteria a little to find the dupe. :)

PRINT() is a thing, but it sounds like the DBA for whatever reason is not giving you that output.
Instead, you could try RAISERROR() with a benign error level, like this:
 RAISERROR ('Message Here', 10,1) WITH NOWAIT

The WITH NOWAIT is because SQL Server might batch or buffer the output. This helps make sure things say in sequence with the rest of the script.

I think that if you would like to see messages you have two options;
1)PRINT -> You can print messages with this command
2)RAISERROR() -> In normal conditions this function used to throw an exception but if you it in text level then you can see messages like print.
Example for raiserror -> RAISERROR('Some Message',10,1) WITH NOWAIT
Be careful for the level. 10 normal text, 16 is error if you use bigger value then 20 you can cause a SQL Serve shutdown, so be careful.
If you need a log then Step1 completed etc. you can log the steps in a table/temp table or you can declare a variable push your logs and return it if there is any.
Besides you can create a try-catch structure so you can see that which step is failing and you can fix it step by step. Logs can be your footsteps and even if there is some exception if you return the log then you can see what are you doing.
Example;
DECLARE @stepLOgs nvarchar(max) = N''

BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 1
    SET @stepLogs = @stepLogs + 'Step1 Success'
    SELECT 2
    SET @stepLogs = @stepLogs + 'Step2 Success'
    SELECT 5/0
    SET @stepLogs = @stepLogs + 'Step3 Success'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @stepLogs = @stepLogs + 'Exception Caught'
END CATCH

SELECT * FROM string_split(@stepLogs,',')

